# Windows on ec2 spot instance: can I reboot?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm running a windows ec2 spot instance. I know we cannot start/stop the instance, and I realize that it can be killed at any time, but can we reboot windows? I.e. will it come back up with the same IP address, same settings, etc.

Root device (30GB) type is ebs. We also have a second volume (140GB) attached. Key data is on that second volume; but the installation/configuration on first volume is something we want to avoid. (We set it up using a spot instance before discovering the catches!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spot instances can be rebooted.  A reboot keeps the same hardware, ip address, etc.